# How to get the latest timestamp available for a given metric from Graphite?

Tags: rest, graphite

How would I query the most recent timestamp for a particular metric in Graphite?

Using the [Render API](http://graphite-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#the-render-api-render), I can ask for *all* known datapoints for the metric during a period, but that's both wasteful and unreliable...

Wasteful because it would give me *all* datapoints for the specified period (1 week by default), while I only need one.

Unreliable because the period, whatever I pick, may be too short...

Can it be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, apparently, it [can not be done at the moment](https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web/issues/2043). Maybe, Graphite-developers will add the necessary API some day.